# How do I add alternative text to an object?

Tags: html, alt, html-object

If I had an object like this:

```
 <p><object classid="…" height="…" width="…"><param name="…"value="…"/>
 <param name="…" value="…" /><param name="…" value="…" />
 <object data="…" height="…" type="…"><param name="…" value="…" />
 <param name="…" value="…" /></object></object></p>
```

Where would I put the alt tag so that the user will see text? The object that's being displayed in this code is a video and I've looked online for a solution, but I can't seem to find a clear answer. (The triple dots are just there to replace the code)

Comment: What do you mean with "so that the user will see text"?

Answer (score 10):

Just add alternative text between the tags like this:

```
<object data="img/failedToLoad.png" type="image/png">Alternative Text</object>
```

Answer (score 3):

To provide alternate text for `<object>` element, for example, to pass Google Lighthouse checks, use `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby` attributes, see:

**aria-label** approach:

```html
<object data="img.svg" type="image/svg+xml" aria-label="Alternative Text">Alternative Text</object>
```

**aria-labelledby** approach:

```html
<span id="label-uid">Alternative Text</span>
<object data="img.svg" type="image/svg+xml" aria-labelledby="label-uid">Alternative Text</object>
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(10rem, min-content));
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  align-items: end;
}

.object-wrapper object {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="object-wrapper">
    <object data="img.svg" type="image/svg+xml" aria-label="Alternative Text">Alternative Text</object>
  </div>

  <div class="object-wrapper">
    <span id="label-uid">Alternative Text - Label</span>
  
    <object data="img.svg" type="image/svg+xml" aria-labelledby="label-uid">Alternative Text</object>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lighthouse (and the [linked rule](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.8/object-alt)) does not give any explanation why using the body of the <object> element is not sufficient. Are there any good reasons for this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition of [`object`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element), the fallback content to be rendered when the object rendering fails is the element’s content. More exactly, it consists of all children of the `object` element except `param` elements. In fact, the sketchy code in the question contains such fallback content: the inner `object` element is fallback content for the outer one. To have a fallback for the fallback, put it inside the inner `object` element; it can be any content, including text:

```html
 <p><object classid="..." height="..." width="..."><param name="..."value="...">
 <param name="..." value="..." /><param name="..." value="..." />
 <object data="..." height="..." type="..."><param name="..." value="..." />
 <param name="..." value="..." />This is fallback content.</object></object></p>
```

Note: Being fallback or alternate content means that the text is *not* displayed when object embedding is successful, i.e. a video presentation is shown.